# HttpPost method receiving wrong data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two methods:

```
    public ActionResult EditNote(int? id)
    {
        NotesModel edit = NotesProcessor.LoadNote(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        if (edit.Author != Session["UserName"].ToString())
        {
            edit.Id = null;
            edit.Title = null;
            edit.Note = null;
            edit.Author = null;
            return View(edit); 
        }
        return View(edit);          
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditNote(NotesModel model)
    {            
        if(model.Id == null) NotesProcessor.SaveNoteEdit(model);
        else
        {
            model.Author = Session["UserName"].ToString();
            NotesProcessor.SaveNote(model);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I've simplified the code to only show the problematic part which is:

A logged in user is trying to edit a note which they're not allowed to because it was made by another user. So all the values are set to null so the user will create a new note. The first method will receive an id to search the database for the note the user is trying to edit.

In the next HttpPost method however model.Id is still the same as the integer received by the first method despite changing all the values to null in the first method.

The first method is called from the views page like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditNote", new { id = Model.Id })
```

Anyone got an idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not posting anything to the system as it seems, you are just calling the HttpGet method via URL and then clearing out the view model data at page level only. So, it seems your HttPost method is not even hitting. Try debugging and see whether your HttpPost method gets hit.

You don,t even need to create two methods for what you want to achieve. All you need is just single HttpPost method.

For HtpPost method to be called, you need to either create Form control at UI level with action type as post or you need to hit HttpPost method via JavaScript / JQuery

I hope this helps.

Comment: The HttpPost works for sure because it is submitting data to the database that i enter in the form control on the html page. however it is still receiving an integer which is not meant for the HttpPost for reasons i can't figure out.
Also I'm pretty sure i need both methods if i only use the HttpPost method it will send my model to the database before any edits are made (also 404 error).